# How to use USB-SSD for virtual memory?

Tags: ssd, swap

I am trying to build a library on my machine from source, but it fails due to not enough virtual memory. I was told that I could maybe get around this by mounting a SSD and using that as a swap space to expand the memory of my system for the duration of the build.

The problem is, I don't understand how to actually do that in Linux.

From what I understand, I need to find the name of the device file which gets associated with the SSD after I plug it in, and then do something like

```
mount DEVICE_FILE /mnt
```

which should make the SSD accessible to me, then in some way assign that directory as a virtual swap space, and then try running my build again.

I believe the way to find the device file is to use dmesg | tail, which gives me this:

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
usb 1-1.3: reset low-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ci_hdrc
usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0 USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0
scsi 0:0:0:0 Direct-Access Seagate Expansion 9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
```

But I don't know what from that is supposed to be the device file I am looking for. I also do not understand how to set the /mnt space as virtual memory.

Can someone explain the method of doing this?

Comment: I think putting the swap file on your internal hard drive would give you better performance than an external SSD connected through any USB. USB is slow.

Comment: I trust you know the size of that SSD? In `gparted` it should then be easy to spot your device and even easier to create a swap file on it.

Comment: Before starting any action, just make sure what you mean with "virtual memory". What tells you that? Did you try `top` to see if your swap space is even used? Usually, "virtual memory" means address space in the process list, not any sort of real memory. See e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/138427/top-what-does-virtual-memory-size-mean-linux-ubuntu.

Comment: And for more explanation: https://www.logicmonitor.com/blog/what-is-virtual-memory-anyway/